# Google Sheets - Query, select x or y and excluded 0 results

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula

Keep getting `#VALUE!` or `#ERROR` on everything I try, I think I'm using the wrong function entirely but don't know the best alternative.

I've tried a few IF blanks and what not but no luck, I've only just started on google sheets a few days ago.

I've tried a query I used on another sheet and changed it around a little, I had some success but with my lack of knowledge.... it didn't do everything I needed and it didn't work when I tried to use it involving all the sheets I needed, just a single sheet it worked for. I tried to search for something but I was just going in circles.

```
=QUERY({KME!$A$2:$D$157;'KME1'!$A$2:$D$157;'KME2'!$A$2:$D$157},"select * WHERE C < 300 OR D <10000",1)
```

```
=QUERY(KME!$A$2:$D$157,"select * WHERE C < 300 OR D <10000",1)
```

I have a set of data across 3 sheets. I need to filter the data, I want it to select all the data which I used `select *` for.

I want it to only show results from:
Column C if below 300 
**OR** 
Column D if below 10,000

I also want it to not show results that have empty cells in C and D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it like this:

```
=QUERY({KME!A2:D157; 'KME1'!A2:D157; 'KME2'!A2:D157}, 
 "where Col3 < 300 
     or Col4 < 10000
    and Col3 !='' 
    and Col4 !='' ", 0)
```

or like this:

```
=QUERY(QUERY({KME!A2:D157;'KME1'!A2:D157;'KME2'!A2:D157},
 "where Col3 < 300 OR Col4 <10000", 0),
 "where Col3 is not null and Col4 is not null")
```

Comment: It delivers results but it still shows empty cells in the results

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DYHl1UgQVA6w3NIquGF6Xz3hq6E0OEEqaCJdb_RNR2k/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: try: `=QUERY(QUERY({KME!$A$2:$D$157;'KME1'!$A$2:$D$157;'KME2'!$A$2:$D$157},"select * WHERE Col3 < 300 OR Col4 <10000",0),"where Col3 is not null and Col4 is not null")`